# difference in SAML metadata vs SAML request and response

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

I am always confused between SAML metadata and SAML request/response between SP and IDP in SSO.
To me, it looks same, as both are xml files.
Can someone tell me the difference between them and how to generate metadata for SP or IDP?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

SAML metadata is information about parties in a SAML communication. A SP and IdP typically exchange these when first setting up a integration. They contain in formation about how to communicate with each other. The IdP will send one with endpoints, protocols and keys on its side and the SP will do the same.

So the metadata is exchanged ones before any user authentication.
When its time to authenticate a user the SP looks in a IdP metadata to understand where and how to send the user to the IdP.

Each user is sent to the IdP using a SAML Authentication Request. Ones authenticated the result of the authentication is sent in a SAML Response.

So, sum. Metadata is sent one to set up integration. SAML request/response is sent ones per per user to authenticate.

I have a post on metadata in more detail. [Metadata exchange and trust](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/post/matadata-exchange-trust/)

Comment: I am little confused while reading your blog.   "When the SP send the authentication request to the IdP together with the users. It usually signs it. It does so with its private key"   ------->   as per my knowledge private key is only used to encrypt the message ...not decrypt......for decryption we use private key at sender end.

Comment: If a public private keypair is used for signing, as in your quote, the private key of the sender is used to sign the message and the public key is used by the receiver to verify the message. If the key pair is used for encryption, the public key is used to encrypt the message and the private key is used to decrypt it.